# Create tags by name programmatically

Tags: tags, joomla3.8

I'm looking to create tags programmatically. I've done it through a direct DB `insert` but that doesn't seem to be working correctly as I can't associated those created tags with a piece of content via the observer.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
$content = JTable::getInstance("Content", 'JTable', array());
$content->load($id);
JHelperTags::addTags(array("tag1", "tag2"), $content);
```

[`JHelperTags`](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.CMS.Helper.TagsHelper.html#method_tagItem) has a method that may do what I want, but I don't understand the arguments. The following does not work

```
$h = new JHelperTags();
$h->tagItem($content->id, $content, array("tag1", "tag2"));
```

How can I programmatically create tags that will be correctly stored in Joomla?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to use [`createTagsFromField`](https://www.phoca.cz/joomla/api/class-JHelperTags.html#_createTagsFromField). `#new#` has to be appended to the title if the tag doesn't exist.

```
$title = "Tag Title";
$h = new JHelperTags;
$h->createTagsFromField(array("#new#$title"));
```